# dotnet test --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" not consider Api project

Tags: c#, azure-devops, asp.net-core-6.0, cobertura, coverlet

I am trying to generate Code coverage report in 2 ways.

1. Using `Fine Code Coverage`. There i see all 3 projects of me covered & its % of coverage.
2. Using Azure devops Pipeline where i use `DotNetCoreCLI@2`& `PublishCodeCoverageResults@1` to build & generate the report. **But the issue is API project is not considered in the report. both in trx & xml file.**

So i tried MSBuild commands to repro the issue. To run the test cases & to build the xml file i am using below command.

```
dotnet test --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"
```

After that to publish the coverage using below command.

```
dotnet test /p:CollectCoverage=true
```

Issue:-
In above command also , i don't see my Api Project is getting into report, where as i see the API layer unit test are running.

Below is my project structure( using clean code architecture/Onion architecture)

[image]

**Why only API is getting excluded , where as all unit test are running for the same.**

Comment: Does your webapi project add nuget reference?

Comment: Yes it have all reference, i.e., Webapi.csproj,Infrastructure.csproj & Application.csproj. When i am running test suite from Local, i can see API layer execution , same when i run it from Pipeline, also i can see the Run for API layer.

Answer (score 0):

Look into your unit test project file, if you see this package reference:

```
<PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector">
   <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
   <IncludeAssets>
     runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive
   </IncludeAssets>
 </PackageReference>
```

Replace it with this:

```
<PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector"/>
```